# strange behaviour in Scala : private[packageName] class A(val s:Int) hides the type A but s is still accessible from another package, why?

Tags: scala

Consider this code:

```
package Example1 {

  package thePackage {

    // PRIVATE test class with PUBLIC field
    private[thePackage] class VisibilityTest(value: String, val valueVisible: Int ) 

    // WRAPPER
    class Wrapper {
      val visibilityTest = new VisibilityTest( "Value set by Wrapper object.", 43 )
    }

  }

  object Tester extends App {
    val wrapper = new thePackage.Wrapper()

//    val wrapped: thePackage.VisibilityTest = wrapper.visibilityTest; // compile ERROR

    val wrapped = wrapper.visibilityTest; // COMPILES FINE -> ????????

//    println(wrapped.value) // ERROR -> as it should be, since value's getter is private
    println( wrapped.valueVisible ) // no ERROR -> ?????????

  }

}
```

I have 2 questions, how is it possible that :

- `println( wrapped.valueVisible )` gives no compile error, but `val wrapped: thePackage.VisibilityTest = wrapper.visibilityTest;` does ?
- `val wrapped = wrapper.visibilityTest` compiles fine but `val wrapped: thePackage.VisibilityTest = ...` does not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have marked `VisibilityTest` as private inside `thePackage` so you can't refer to `thePackage.VisibilityTest` outside `thePackage`. This is why the statements that explicitly refer to `thePackage.VisibilityTest` do not compile.

You can, however, place instances of a `private` class in a `public` class, which is what happens with `Wrapper`. And since the instance is not private, you can inspect the contents of that instance without violating the privacy of the class itself.

This is not a standard way to write this sort of code. The `private` class will usually extend a non-private `trait` that defines the external behaviour. Using this model the value in the public class would be given the type of the non-private trait so that the private information does not leak out.

Also note that `value` is not a member, it is just a parameter to the constructor, so it does not have a getter. (To confuse things, the current compiler will place this value in the object and provide a getter, but this is not part of the language specificaition)

Comment: Thanks Tim :) 

What do you mean by "since instance is not private, you can inspect the contents of that instance without violating the privacy of the class itself." ?

Which instance is not private ? Can an instance be private ? I was thinking only fields and classes and objects and methods can be private ... I am confused :)

Comment: "This is not a standard way to write this sort of code. The private class will usually extend a non-private trait that defines the external behaviour. Using this model the value in the public class would be given the type of the non-private trait so that the private information does not leak out." <<< Thanks ! I need to give this a try next weekend :) when I have time again to code on my "baby-project" which led me to this question (as I am "still" learning Scala, after 6 years ... ) :) .